# When using an OR operator, will the query return left condition over the right?

Tags: sql, operators, where-clause, operator-keyword

I want to return a **single** row but want one query to qualify the two conditions.

For example

```sql
SELECT * FROM user WHERE admin < 10 OR admin > 100 LIMIT 1
```

When I query this, will this return the first row it finds that has an admin value less than 10? If not, how would I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  This returns the first row that matches the `where` clause.  If you want the first row that matches `admin < 10`, then remove `or amin > 100`.

Comment: I want to find the first row that has `admin < 10`, but if there are no rows that have that value then I want to return the first row that has `admin > 100`. I think the sample query is simple enough to provide an answer, the sample data would confuse things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `order by`.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE admin < 10 OR admin > 100
ORDER BY admin
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> I want to find the first row that has admin < 10, but if there are no rows that have that value then I want to return the first row that has admin > 100

One option uses `union all` and `not exists`:

```
(select * from users where admin < 10 limit 1)
union all
(
    select * 
    from users 
    where 
        admin > 100 
        and not exists (select 1 from users where admin < 10)
    limit 1
)
```

Another solution is to do a conditional sort:

```
select *
from users 
where admin < 10 and admin > 100
order by case when admin < 10 then 1 else 2 end
limit 1
```

Note that your query would make more sense if you were to add an `order by` clause to it. Using `limit` without `order by` results in an *abritrary* row being returned out of those that satisfy the predicates.

Comment: When using `UNION ALL`, wouldn't the query you wrote here return 2 rows?

Comment: @Xylum: the second subquery returns something only if the first subquery did not (that's the purpose of `not exists`).